# running per application unittests from django admin

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

Is there any application or some configuration that allows one to run tests in each django-app/tests.py file from the admin panel ? Some thing like an extra link 'test' that runs all tests for that application ad outputs the result.

Is there something that already exists for such purpose ? If not then what would be the best strategy to implement it.

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such configuration. And it would not make much sense to test within the admin. The purpose of admin interface is to allow data manipulation. The tests don't (or should not) even operate on the data in the live system. The CLI is perfect to test the django app.

Comment: The purpose of admin is website management - what that entails depends entirely on the type of website and structure of the development team. For the same reason, there exist many customizations of admin - some offer image previews,maps and even analytics (django-piwik). In anycase, it would've been more useful had you offered anything constructive rather than just questioning the usecase in the absence of any information.

Comment: Then, I'm sorry to say, you are ignorant to my advice and have not understood the concepts of the django architecture (and the architecture of other web frameworks as well). On SO you'll sometimes find valuable answers to your questions and sometimes you'll get hints to what may be wrong with your question in the first place. But again, this is just my *opinion*, maybe there is a perfectly good reason why you want to implement this, but at the current state of information, I simply cannot spot it.

Comment: Use popen to start "manage.py test"